# What and why is `docs` keyword in `make`?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I tried to add docs generation to a basic Makefile:

```
build: fmt docs
    # ...

docs:
    tfplugindocs

# ...
```

```
$ make docs
make: 'docs' is up to date.
$ tfplugindocs
[... does the business]
```

Hm, ok, edit the Makefile:

```
build: fmt doc
    # ...

doc:
    tfplugindocs
```

```
$ make doc
[... does the business]
```

So I assume `docs` is some kind of keyword either on the CLI or in the Makefile; so it doesn't do what I expect when I try to use it just as a name for an 'ordinary' target. But I can't find any mention of it in the manual or help page.

What does it do, how, and should I be using it?

Comment: I'm guessing the working directory actually contains a real file or directory named `docs`?  Since it already exists, is not a `PHONY` target and has no dependencies then `make` doesn't see any need to rebuild it.

Comment: @G.M. Ah, it does! I didn't know it worked like that, or that that was what `PHONY` was for. Thanks.